# Relation between users and local database tables in an external Identity provider service

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have created a asp.net application Authenticate with external identity provider (Azure Active Directory)

how can I create relation between users and local database tables ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the either the user's `id` or `UPN` (userPrincipalName) from Active Directory in your own data store. Both of these fields are in the token you get from AD. In [Access Tokens - Payload claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) you see both the `oid` field and the `upn` field are available. My preference would be to use the `oid`.

> **id**
>   The unique identifier for the user. Inherited from directoryObject. Key. Not nullable. Read-only.
>
> **userPrincipalName**
>   The user principal name (UPN) of the user. The UPN is an Internet-style login name for the user based on the Internet standard RFC 822. By convention, this should map to the user's email name. The general format is alias@domain, where domain must be present in the tenant’s collection of verified domains. This property is required when a user is created. The verified domains for the tenant can be accessed from the verifiedDomains property of organization. Supports $filter and $orderby.

Source: [user resource type - Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

This will enable you to track back to a specific user in AD.

Comment: How can I add azure ad users in my local DB